# Android wear works only on signed .apk

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, wear-os

**Description:**
I've phone app and wear app - which works only with phone app.
I've recently updated target and compile SDK to 27.
I've been testing performance on Android P preview, but accidentally I've found problem on all devices.

**Problem:**
Wear app can't communicate with phone app (and vice-versa) while installing both apps as "run" from Android Studio.

On the other hand - When I generate signed APK with key both release/debug versions of app communicate with each other (phone app & wear app) - **OK**

I have same "applicationId" for both apps.
Also it does not seems to be problem related to code, as both app works on signed APKs.

**Any idea what can be wrong?**

Comment: Try to upload phone app to device/emulator which is connected to another wear device/emulator and let wear app be installed automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolved**
As mentioned in documentation:
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/

> Important: Your phone and Wear APK signatures and the signature schemes must to be identical for the DataLayer API to be able to successfully communicate between devices. This includes your usage of the v1 and/or v2 signature. **Ensure the signature scheme is set correctly in build.gradle or when you use the Generate Signed APK wizard**

I have added in each (Wearable and phone) build.gradle

```
android {
        signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("myKey.keystore")
        }
    }
...
}
```

about keystore.

> When **running** or debugging your project from the IDE, Android Studio
>   **automatically signs your APK** with a debug certificate generated by the
>   Android SDK tools. The first time you run or debug your project in
>   Android Studio, the IDE automatically creates the debug keystore and
>   certificate in **$HOME/.android/debug.keystore**, and sets the keystore
>   and key passwords.

source: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Comment: Could you add more detailed solution? For example where to get keystores from and where exactly this chunk of code should be placed.